# Z test or t test

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

[image]

I am torn between z test and t test. I am leaning towards z test because by the Central Limit Theorem $102>30$ and $69>30$. Am I wrong in my assertion? What do I need to look out for in deciding if to use a z test or t test aside when $\sigma$ is known or not.

Comment: When the population standard deviation is unknown (as here) and therefore estimated by the sample standard deviation, the t distribution is used to find confidence intervals for population means and to test hypotheses about differences of population means. // That said, in the **special case of 95%** confidence intervals for samples as large as yours, the values you find in a z table will be very close to the correct t value. For $n=69,$ the values are 1.9955 for t and 1.9600 for z. (Even closer for $n=102.)$ // _Be careful:_ Don't use such an approximation for 99% CIs.

Comment: That closeness is why you were told those >30 rules of thumb. You can think of it as a vestige of when computation was expensive, so the cutoff for using the easier but less accurate z vs t was chosen to be 30 back then.

Comment: Without actually saying so, the question seems to imply that the CIs for Baseline and for Follow-up are independent--and comparable. Presumably, the 69 follow-up patients were some of the same patients as the 102 in the baseline. // A more responsible analysis would compare baseline and follow-up values only for the 69 patients present for both. // Especially in this problem, it is fair to wonder what happened to the 33 subjects missing from the follow-up. (Feeling so great, one hopes, that they have no patience for follow-up or terribly sick or dead, and so couldn't participate.)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use a t-test. Since you are using a $cohort$ of individuals with the disease (i.e., a sample) you should use the t-distribution. Only use a z-test (Normal distribution) when you are testing something on a population (which in practice isn't super often).